# Горячие клавиши в TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть `TreeView`, к которому биндятся команды копирования/вставки/удаления узлов с горячими клавишами.

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="C" 
                    Command="{Binding CopyCommand}"/>
        <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="V" 
                    Command="{Binding PasteCommand}"/>
        <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="X" 
                    Command="{Binding CutCommand}"/>
        <KeyBinding Key="Delete" 
                    Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
    </TreeView.InputBindings>
</TreeView>
```

Проблема в том, что команды вызываются только если выделить какой-нибудь узел в дереве.

К примеру, если я выделю узел и вырежу его, то так как не будет фокуса на другом узле, команда вставки не сработает и нужно будет перед вставкой выделять другой узел.

Если биндить команды уровням выше, например на окно, то все работает, но нужно, чтобы команды срабатывали только когда идет работа в `TreeView`.

Что делать?

Comment: 'К примеру, если я выделю узел и вырежу его, то так как не будет фокуса на другом узле': ставьте фокус после удаления узла на первый/последний/предыдущий узел, м?

Comment: События от клавиатуры доставляются элементу, который держит фокус. Попробуйте установить фокус после удаления элемента.

Comment: @AK, @VladD, Установка фокуса на другой узел помогает. А если я вырезаю все элементы можно ли установить фокус на `TreeView` без кликов по нему? Удаление происходит в ViewModel и доступа к контролу нет.

Comment: @maxwel попробуйте обработку события TreeView.LostFocus